# Reference an object embedded in another sheet

Tags: excel

I would like to know how to reference a Word document embedded in another sheet.

I have learned how to embed a Word document in an Excel sheet, but I need to copy that sheet several times.

I assume that if I copy the sheet along with the Word document I will have also replicated the document on the new sheet.

I would like to be able to copy the sheet without the document and then reference the document embedded in the other sheet.

I've searched for information, but everything I find is about the opposite, Excel sheets embedded in Word.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.